# MATLAB Find all files in folder with subfolders with extension .txt and read with textscan

Tags: matlab, text, directory

I want to find all files with extension .txt in a folder with sub folders. These sub folders contain .txt-files which I want to read using the textscan function.

The .txt-files contain numbers and a header line:

```
A B C D
1 0.4 23 42
2 0.3 32 34
```

Here is what I tried. But I get always the error:

```
Error using fopen
Invalid permission.
```

What do I wrong? I already tried to work with code I found in the internet but it does not work for my problem.

```
dirinfo = dir();
    dirinfo(~[dirinfo.isdir]) = [];  %remove non-directories

    subdirinfo = cell(length(dirinfo));
    for k = 1 : length(dirinfo)
        thisdir = dirinfo(k).name;
        subdirinfo{k} = dir(fullfile(thisdir, '*.txt'));

        for m=1:length(subdirinfo)
            for n=1:length(subdirinfo{m})
                fileID = fopen(subdirinfo{m,n}.name);
                C = textscan(fileID,'%f32 %f32 %f32 %f32','HeaderLines',1);
                fclose(fileID);
                % do stuff
            end
        end 
    end
```

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is basically fine, but you should get rid of the '.' and '..' directories, only make one subquery going over the subdirinfo, and you need to give fopen the directory:

```
dirinfo = dir();
dirinfo(~[dirinfo.isdir]) = [];  %remove non-directories
dirinfo(ismember({dirinfo.name}, {'.', '..'})) = [];
subdirinfo = cell(length(dirinfo), 1);
for k = 1 : length(dirinfo)
    thisdir = dirinfo(k).name;
    subdirinfo{k} = dir(fullfile(thisdir, '*.txt'));
    for n=1:length(subdirinfo{k})
        fileID = fopen(fullfile(thisdir, subdirinfo{k}(n).name));
        C = textscan(fileID,'%f32 %f32 %f32 %f32','HeaderLines',1);
        fclose(fileID);
        % do stuff
    end
end
```